# Can users filter the level of activity for New Questions on the main page by tags?

Tags: discussion, support

Compared to the last time I posted on MSE, the activity on the main page seems very high: **Approximately 30 new questions/hour**. It therefore looks to me that any question which hasn't attracted any interest within the first hour is unlikely to be answered at all.

Can perhaps users reduce the level of activity on the main page to manageable levels by filtering questions by a group of tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, click on your profile, then go on "Edit Profile & settings" there you can filter the questions by tags (you can hide or grey the tags you don't want and choose some favorite tags). Should be [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current#interesting-tags).

Comment: NB I added the appropriate page anchor so a user doesn't have to scroll down to the tag boxes.

Comment: @AlexR nice! how did you find the link?

Comment: I just looked for a page anchor (`<div id="...">`) somewhere near the relevant part, because I had to look for it as well ^^ Firebug is my best friend to that regard. Note that the anchor is imperfect in so far that the heading "Tags" is above it, but that's the closest you can get with plain hyperlinks.

Comment: @AlexR ok thanks for the trick :).